# Google Script Confirmation Popup Success message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to add Confirmation Popup message for updateData function in my below html form and script..

When User has been updated successfully after clicking `Submit Button` Ex: `{User} has been updated`, were User name is in `Column B` In Spreadsheet.
When User has been Deleted successfully after clicking `Delete Button` Ex: `{User} has been deleted`, were User name is in `Column B` In Spreadsheet.

`Update User`

```
function updateData(values, spreadsheetId, range) {
  var colDailyChanges = 9;
  var colDailyLogs = 10;
  values[0][colDailyLogs - 1] = values[0][colDailyLogs - 1] ? `${values[0][colDailyLogs - 1]}\n${values[0][colDailyChanges - 1]}` : values[0][colDailyChanges - 1];
  values[0][colDailyChanges - 1] = "";

  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = values;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range, { valueInputOption: "RAW" });
}
```

`Delete User`

```
function deleteData(el) {
    var result = confirm("Want to delete?");
    if (result) {
      var recordId = el.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).deleteData(recordId);
    }
  }
```

Html

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" >Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="last" >Last</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last" name="last" placeholder="Last" required>
    </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Spreadsheet and Google Script Link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tyz_3WeEkmY4WX8Xvx38nkLow8hcbCjPMLS1-NiPFgo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: While a link to your spreadsheet might be helpful questions on this site should be self-contained. Please add a [mcve] directly into the question body.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would consider putting it in the SuccessHandler in this function:

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
      createTable();
      //launch dialog here with window.open or JQuery Dialogs or even possibly a previously hidden message div
    })
    .processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I already have ```handleFormSubmit``` in my Javascript.html file you can check in my above link. but I want a to add a custom popup message in html form when clicked submit after successfully updated in spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes I realize that.  Did you read my comment how do you want to do it.  Personally, I'd favor the msg in a hidden div because it's trivial to do.

Comment: Can i get sample code were and how to add ?

Comment: Try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) or [here](https://html.com/javascript/popup-windows/)